# Postfix Relay Loops Back To Myself

Tags: linux, windows, postfix, exchange, smtp

I have 2 servers, let me illustration like this:

Server A = **Exchange Server (mail.fendyfy.com)**
Server B = **SMTP Server (Postfix) on VPS (smtp.fendyfy.com)**

I want my server A to fully **Send&Receive** emails from server B (because server A port 25 is blocked by ISP)
Now I already can **Send external emails** using smarthost and **configuring the port to 587**
But I **can't receive external emails**, the email status is **Bounced**. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

There are the error logs when I try sending from **Gmail**:

```
smtp postfix/relay/smtp[13454]: A303C201AA: to=<administrator@fendyfy.com>, relay=none, delay=0.47, delays=0.45/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced
```

(mail for fendyfy.com loops back to myself)

This is my Postfix configuration:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination<br>
myhostname = mail.fendyfy.com<br>
mydomain = fendyfy.com<br>
myorigin = $mydomain<br>
mydestination =<br>
local_recipient_maps =<br>
relayhost =<br>
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0<br>
relay_domains = fendyfy.com<br>
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"<br>
mailbox_size_limit = 0<br>
recipient_delimiter = +<br>
inet_interfaces = all<br>
inet_protocols = all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the relay server IP to the receive connector in exchange server? If not, follow these guidance：[Receive connectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/connectors/receive-connectors?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchserver-2019) and [How to Configure a Relay Connector for Exchange Server 2010](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/how-to-configure-a-relay-connector-for-exchange-server-2010/)

In addition, a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/129ee10d-e5c5-40e0-9646-a2724af01647/postfix-as-relay-to-exchange?forum=exchangesvr3rdpartyappslegacy) for your reference as well.

Sorry for that I'm not familiar with Postfix, but i have done some research, here are some solutions in the blog for your reference: [Postfix mail for domain.com loops back to myself Error and Solution](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-mail-for-domaincom-loops-back-to-myself-error-and-solution/)